# Find-Package works but Install-Package shows only nuget error using chocolatey in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget, package-managers, chocolatey

I'm just getting start using Windows for my personal programming projects. I am trying the following in Powershell 5.1 as admin:

```
PS >install-package nodejs -providername Chocolatey
```

and I get the following error:

```
WARNING: NuGet: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '13.12.0' of package 'nodejs.install'.
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.PackageRepositoryHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository sourceRepository,
IPackageRepository localRepository, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, String packageId, SemanticVersion
version, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Boolean
ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.Commands.InstallCommand.InstallPackage(IFileSystem fileSystem, String packageId,
SemanticVersion version)
WARNING: NuGet:    at NuGet.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Even though it's just a warning, the package is not installed:

```
PS >get-package nodejs
get-package : No package found for 'nodejs'.
```

Some commands to show the package environment. All I've really done is install chocolatey, set it as trusted,  and register the source:

```
PS >find-package nodejs -providername Chocolatey

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
nodejs                 13.12.0          chocolatey       Node JS - Evented I/O for v8 JavaScript.

PS >get-packagesource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
chocolatey                       Chocolatey       True       http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    False      https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

PS >get-executionpolicy
AllSigned
```

This goes for other packages that are commonly used in examples, e.g. vlc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I was typing "y" in response to the "Are you sure..." query rather than "Y". I was thrown off by the delay and warnings instead of it immediately terminating.